# Sending emails using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, mariadb

I'm working for a project that can send bulk emails. I'm currently at 100 emails per 1:06 seconds. I think it can be done faster like in a minute or under. Do you have any suggestions?

I've already done using threading/multi-threading, but of course "GIL".
I've done also from multiprocessing. That's where I get the 1:06 seconds, and pool for 1:07 seconds

```py
def sendMail(z,x,c):
    startti=datetime.datetime.now()
    server.sendmail(z,x,c)
    timenow= datetime.datetime.now()
    print (timenow-startti).total_seconds()

def multiprocessing_func(x):
    cursor.execute(query)
    starttime=datetime.datetime.now()
    while True:
        result=cursor.fetchone()
        if result==None:
            break
        subject=str(result[1])
        sendto=str(result[2])

        msg=MIMEMultipart('mixed')
        msg['from']=mail_sender
        msg['to']=sendto
        msg['subject']=subject

        part_text=MIMEText(html, 'html')
        msg.attach(part_text)
        msg.attach(file1)

        sendMail(msg['from'],msg['to'],msg.as_string())

    endtime=datetime.datetime.now()
    print'%s'%(endtime-starttime)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes=[]
    for i in range(1):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=multiprocessing_func, args=(i,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join
```

Comment: SInce you are ` for i in range(1):` you are launching one process at a time. So it is effectively sequential. Try a higher number like ` for i in range(20):`

Comment: if i make it 20, it calls the whole table 20 times

Comment: The you need to restructure your code such that 1) `multiprocessing_func` only takes a to_email and subject to send an email 2) move the database query logic from `multiprocessing_func` to the `__main__`.

Comment: The best way is to use asynchronous IO so that you don't block on the network call. If you're making the calls yourself, look at aiohttp or aiosmtpd. If you're using some module abstract sending mails, try to find one that can do async operations.

Comment: i only use mysql.connector and multiprocessing module hoodakaushal

Comment: after trying to modify the code, now i get either this 'InterfaceError: Failed parsing column information' or 'SMTPServerDisconnected: Connection unexpectedly closed'

Comment: In general if you are concerned about the GIL you shouldn't use Python 2. Its GIL is much more aggressive and it's also end of life in half a year. Looking at your code the most latency is coming from network I/O which should release the GIL even in Python 2.7. This means you should be fine with threads if they are used properly.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.  Find out what part of the processing takes the most time.

- Is it the fetching of the data from the database?  100 individual `SELECTs` can be done in 1 second with a suitable index and query formulation; let's see the query.  Fetching 100 rows at a time would be even faster.  If "1:06" means 66 seconds, then I suggest that MySQL is *not* the bottleneck.
- Is it emitting the email, then multi-processing may (*or may not*) run faster.
- Maybe having multiple processes, each running independently (except for not hitting the same rows) would be simpler and faster?

Comment: yes, 1:06 means 66 seconds. i'm receiving the email with no problem. and what do you mean by the 3rd question?